# prevent all elements within a div from being selected. \

Tags: jquery

i am trying to prevent all elements within a div from being selected. this is not working.

`$('*').not('#someid > *')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your approach is that you're asking for *immediate* children. If you remove the `>` it should work fine:

```
$('*').not('#someid *');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter):

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).closest("#someid").length;
})
```

...actually doing some more testing, this should also work:

```
$("*:not(#someid *)")
```

Comment: what if $("*").bind("click",function()

how do i add it then ?

Comment: `$("*").filter(...).bind("click", function() {...})` or
`$("*:not(#someid *)").bind("click", function() {...})`